# How to create a Method and use it inside another Method

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I created a method which uses AFNetworking and gets JSON from a URL. But i cant figure out how to use it inside ViewDidLoad. I either get an error or an empty UITable.

here is my code:

```
@interface QWViewController ()

-(void)loadVideoFromURL:(NSURL *)url;

@end

@interface NSURL()

-(void)loadVideoFromURL:(NSURL *)url;

@end
```

// the method i created:

```
-(void)loadVideoFromURL:(NSURL *)url {

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    // setup AFNetworking stuff
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        // call delegate or processing method on success

        self.myJSON = (NSDictionary *)JSON;

        NSLog(@" json %@", self.myJSON);

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
    }];


    [operation start];

}
```

// Here is ViewWillAppear:

```
   -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    //[super viewDidLoad];



    NSLog(@" video Meta Data %@", self.myJSON);
    // link to the youtube channel or playlist NOTE: JSON and JSONC are not the same. Use JSONC, as far as i recall, its customised for youtube.

    NSString *urlAsString = @"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL7CF5B0AC3B1EB1D5?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=50";

    NSURL *myurl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAsString];

    self.myJSON = [self loadVideoFromURL:myurl];



        // I am using self.videoMetaData. I am defining it in the .h file as a property. This will let me use it anywhere in this .m file.

        self.videoMetaData = [self.myJSON valueForKeyPath:@"data.items.video"];

        NSLog(@" JSON view will apear %@", self.myJSON);

        // This will have all the sq and hq thumbnails

       // self.allThumbnails = [urlcontent valueForKeyPath:@"data.items.video.thumbnail"];


        // The table need to be reloaded or else we will get an empty table.

        [self.tableView reloadData]; // Must Reload

        // NSLog(@" video Meta Data %@", self.videoMetaData);

}
```

Comment: setting data should be done in viewWillAppear

Comment: Read the [Objective-C Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html). It will clear things up for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your return type is void for `loadVideoFromURL`,

You can not assign the value like this

```
NSURL *urlcontent = [self loadVideoFromURL:myurl];
```

unless you have return type of method `loadVideoFromURL` as `NSURL`.

Therefore you should call your method like this without assigning it to urlcontent in your situation

```
[self loadVideoFromURL:myurl];
```

Comment: you should post your updated code, when you assigning value then you should make sure that you are returning something from method. are you returning *NSData` or `NSMutableArray` from the method now?

Comment: Changed to NSMutableArray.

Comment: I am returning NSDictionary from the Method.

Comment: if you return the `NSDictionary` then  it should work, just assign it to a `NSDictionary` and use the values by getting `valueForKey` within `NSDictionary`  do like this  `NSDictionary *dict=[self loadVideoFromURL:myurl];`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24453/discussion-between-gulliver007-and-user1951876)

Comment: not working. it says: NSDictionary *__strong' with an expression of incompatible type 'void'

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSURL *urlcontent = [self loadVideoFromURL:myurl];
```